# How to align between two items inline left and right using flex in react native

Tags: css, react-native

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to align the `2 messages` text label next to bargraph with background color green. The bargraph has dynamic width which renders coming from the backend and when size grows, the `2 messages` label should also adjust and is always next to bargraph.

[image: expected output]

And here's what I have done sofar. It seems like that `2 messages` won't show up next to bargraph with green background.

[image: done sofar]

component code:

```
                        <View style={[styles.container]}>
                            <View style={[styles.barGraph, styles.greenDeep]}>
                                <View style={{ flex: 6 }}>
                                    <Text style={styles.textLeft}>agree</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ flex: 6}}>
                                    <Text style={styles.textRight}>3 (60 %)</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <Text>2 messages</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
```

css:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignContent: "space-between",
},
textLeft: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'left'
},
textRight: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'right'
},
barGraph: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE,
    width: width - theme.SIZES.BASE * 10,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5
},
greenDeep: {
    backgroundColor: '#36d79a'
},
```

How would it be possible with react native's flex property?
For live editing, visit snack here [live editor](https://snack.expo.dev/@vicrn101/align-two-items-inline-left-and-right-using-flex)

Comment: If possible then share codepen or plunkr link

Comment: what I understand is, give `min-width`, `whiteSpace:nowrap` to last `<view>` child

Comment: heres a live example that you may try https://snack.expo.dev/@vicrn101/align-two-items-inline-left-and-right-using-flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achive this:

[image]

First you have to set your flexDirection of container class to column. Set maxWidth at other container classes, and create a new class for your message with justifyContent: 'center' attribute.

```
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: "row", /*it was column*/ 
  alignContent: "space-between",
}

surveyDetailsContainer: {
    /* some code */
    maxWidth: 500,
},
container: {
    /* some code */
    maxWidth: 500,
},
   /* some other classes*/
barGraph: {
    /* some code */
    maxWidth: 400,
},

/*created a new class, included the minWidth and added 3 more new attributes*/
message: {
  minWidth: 5,
  maxWidth: 80,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  marginLeft: 5,
}
```

And then put the new message class into:

```
<View style={[styles.message]}>
  <Text>2 messages</Text>
</View>
```

Here is the whole code: https://snack.expo.dev/UwP7GVLzX

You can play around more with maxWidth, minWidth to make it responsive.